Why can the resolvent be determined using the euclidian algorithm?
It is fairly common to define the resultant and the $i$-th subresultant as determinant of some matrix involving the sylvester matrix. I would like to avoid the sylvester matrix.
I wonder if it is not possible to show algebraicly that the resolvent
$$\mathrm{res}(a,b) = \prod_{\substack{x_i,y_j\in K \\ a(x_i) = 0 \\ b(y_j) = 0}} (x_i - y_j)$$
can be calculated using the euclidian algorithm, while avoiding the sylvester matrix.

What would be the definition of the $i$-th subresultant?
What is the property of the resultant that connects it with the euclidian algorithm?

The wikipedia-article seems to be misleading here. See my other question here.
